# Loss of index in LIKE operator with prefix "%"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

PL/SQL Developer - Oracle10g

I have a query that is losing index when it's set with a LIKE operator, but only with the prefix "%"

For example:

```
select * from people where name like '%POTATO'
```

its return 'access full' in the table on optimizer goal. 
How do I get a contour solution?

Comment: How would you find all entries in a book that have words ending with POTATO? The index won't show them in a useful order. If you're lucky you might be able to scan through the entire index, manually pick out all the matching words, and follow those index entries to the actual book text. But with a small book and a relatively large index it might be quicker to read through the whole book and look at every word instead, which is essentially what Oracle's optimiser is choosing to do here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'contour solution'? Also, you might want to investigate Oracle Text. If this is something you might do a lot you could consider a function-based index based on the reversed text, which you could then search with 'OTATOP%', but it might be a lot of overhead.

Comment: "When you use `LIKE` to search an indexed column for a pattern, Oracle can use the index to improve performance of a query if the leading character in the pattern is not `%` or `_`. In this case, Oracle can scan the index by this leading character. If the first character in the pattern is `%` or `_`, then the index cannot improve performance because Oracle cannot scan the index." [from Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52146).

Comment: I liked the first comment, I didn't realize that index works like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you think really important to query by such a special name ending, consider creating a `function-based` index :

```
create index idx_special_people
on people(upper(substr(name,-6)));
```

gather table statistics :

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'people', cascade => true);
```

and call as :

```
select * 
  from people 
 where upper(substr(name,-6)) = 'POTATO'
```

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer will cost various approaches, including a full table scan and an index full scan. Presumably its calculations showed that the full table scan would be more efficient. This is quite likely as you would have to full-scan the whole index to find keys ending in 'POTATO', while keys beginning with 'POTATO' are stored together (as in a phonebook).

If you share the table and index details, data volumes and execution plan, someone may be able to advise in more detail.

Answer (score -5):

You can try to use a HINT:

```
select /*+ INDEX(people indexname) */ * from people where name like '%POTATO'
```

Comment: Do, or do not - there is no "try".

Comment: "When you use `LIKE` to search an indexed column for a pattern, Oracle can use the index to improve performance of a query if the leading character in the pattern is not `%` or `_`. In this case, Oracle can scan the index by this leading character. If the first character in the pattern is `%` or `_`, then the index cannot improve performance because Oracle cannot scan the index." [from Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52146).

Comment: Yes @MT0 I read that too, while I had a similar problem. Still I got far better results with the INDEX hint and the explain plan shows that it is used. As there haven't been many cases where I had problems like that and it worked I didn't bother to look deeper. Guess Oracle automatically removes the index but can scan only the index and match vs that and get better performance by issuing distinct comparisons vs that field. So I guess it can be beneficial in terms of a range scan but still had to be a full scan for an unique index. As it gives me 3 vs 60 secs I don't care what the docs say.

Comment: "**cannot** improve performance" is perhaps slightly unhelpful. Oracle can't determine if it would improve performance, and as it often/usually won't and is likely to be *worse*, it has to ignore the index. You are essentially forcing a full index scan, instead of a full table scan, and sometimes that may still be faster - as long as you end up with relatively few hits and so low table-row access (as with any index use). Without caveats this is bad advice, and the danger is someone will try, see the index is used, and assume that is good when it actually isn't for them. It depends on the data,

Comment: Ye but the explain plan will tell you what happens. If OP has 10 different values for his name field and each links to 1 million rows It would be a lot faster to do a INDEX scan, match that vs the LIKE condition and return 1 million rows compared to scan all 10 millions. So it can improve performance. And with the information we got there is nothing more I can tell him but he can try if that will improve the performance in his case.